# Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found when using "apply from:"

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We are trying to organize our various projects by moving common configurations in centralized gradle files that can be included from all the projects. In the process, we are facing some issues

For example, this is root build.gradle for a project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    System.println "Processing"
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is a module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

...
```

This works fine. Now I copied root build.gradle content to some other file and then used "apply from:" inside the root level build.gradle file, which looks like following now

```
apply from: "/code/android/java/buildscripts/root.gradle"
```

Though gradle successfully processes above file (as I can see from println logs), it gives error when it moves to process module level build.gradle file. Error is "Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found"

This is surprising because the same module level gradle file complies successfully when apply from: was not used. I thought "apply from" has the effect of including another gradle file but there seem to be some other side effects.

Any insights?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You are probably running into script classpath isolations (like in https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1262).

Comment: looks like the same issues, thanks for pointing to that link. Unfortunately gradle has poorly documented "apply from" without mentioning any limitations.